# How to output an array to a comma-deliniated string?

Tags: csv, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have an array called `device`, which looks like this (simplified):

```
label : "Device 1",
exhibits : [{
    item : 1,
    desc : "This is a sample"
},{
    item : 2,
    desc : "This is another sample"
},{
    item : 3,
    desc : "This is a third"
}]
```

I'm trying to print `exhibits` neatly for a PDF, so I'm thinking comma-deliniated like this:

```
1, 2, 3
```

This is my code:

```
<cfloop array="#device.exhibits#" index="exhibit">
    #exhibit.item#
</cfloop>
```

But I get this:

```
123
```

Yes, I could manually figure out if there should be commas or not, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could so some sort of `listappend()` but that would not get the spaces.

Comment: My compiler sense is tingling: `itemNumber is undefined in exhibit`. You meant `#exhibit.item#`, right?  :P

Comment: @Alex Yes, thank you, I fixed it to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to extract the data first:

```
<!--- extract the itemNumber of every exhibit --->
<cfset itemNumberList = []>
<cfloop array="#device.exhibits#" index="exhibit">
    <cfset itemNumberList.add(exhibit.itemNumber)>
</cfloop>
```

And then we transform the extracted data to a comma-separated list (string):

```
<cfset itemNumberList = arrayToList(itemNumberList, ", ")>

<!--- 1, 2, 3 --->
<cfoutput>#itemNumberList#</cfoutput>
```

[Array-mapping](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arraymap.html) ([see Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344345/1769733)) is a more fancy (readable?) way.

Comment: Just realized that `.add()` falls back into Java. `.append()` is the CF member function. Personally, I think this integration with parts of Java is one of the very nice things about ColdFusion. I think that Java `.add()` when building an array is fastest.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using CF11+, you can use the `ArrayMap` function with an `ArrayList` to turn the array into a list.

```
exhibits.map( function(i) { return i.item ; } ).toList() ;
```

With your example array, it gives you "`1,2,3`".

In another of my answers, I stepped through handling empty elements. Since this is an array of structs, I don't know if this would be a problem. How are you getting this data for your `exhibits` array?

**EDIT:**

```
exhibits.map( function(i) { return i.item ; } )
    .filter( function(j) { return len(j) ; } )
    .toList() ;
```

will return the list with empty elements removed.

**EDIT 2:**

Per the question by @TravisHeeter, if you prefer lambda expressions or arrow functions, you can use them in Lucee 5.

```
exhibits.map( (i) => i.item ).filter( (j) => len(j) ).toList()
```

https://trycf.com/gist/907a68127ddb704611b191d494aa94ce/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: I take it CF doesn't have [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) yet?

Comment: @TravisHeeter  I don't think Adobe CF does, but Lucee 5 dialect does. See answer update.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not get `.map` nor `arrayMap` to work, I had to use @Alex's solution.

Comment: Are you using CF2016? `ArrayMap` was added back in CF11, so there's no reason it shouldn't work on any modern version of CF. What does your array look like? It may be a referencing problem.

Comment: https://trycf.com/gist/549906a224a65edeba15b8a60674ab0e/acf2016?theme=monokai  << I nested the array like your example, with `device` being the outer array, and by changing the reference to `device.exhibits`, it still works. Does your `device` array have a more complex structure?